# How to configure Wake-On-LAN for home network?

Tags: networking, router, wake-on-lan, gateway

The device which is connected to the Internet is my home gateway Huawei HG8245H5. I have a second device connecting my home gateway and my PC TP-Link TL-WR720N. I was able to use WoL through the Internet in this configuration.

This is my problem now: I don't need the TP-Link anymore and I took it out of the network, I connected my PC to the home gateway and WoL doesn't work anymore. I've sent the WoL packet over the Internet and listened on my PC with this `nc --udp --listen --local-port=9 --hexdump` and the packet comes in its form normally, so I really don't know why it doesn't wake up. I'm not that tech savy about networking but should I reset the home gateway, does it store some cache in it, I remember that the root hub becomes the one with the lowest MAC address the TL starts with 10:... while the Huawei starts with FC:...

Comment: The search term you need for Google is "magic packet over internet".

Comment: The #1 thing that prevents WoL-over-Internet from working is that the router loses the ARP table entry for the sleeping device. You need to configure your router to have a persistent static ARP table entry for the device you want to wake. Many home gateway routers don't provide a way to do this with factory firmware, so you may have to load open source firmware like OpenWrt, or buy a router that supports configuring static ARP mappings.